# How the current steadily flows due to motional EMF?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electromagnetic-induction

In motional EMF, the positive charges (current) flows from higher to lower potential. If this is the case, then the current should stop at the point of lower potential. But this does not happen - the current continues to flow. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps considering a simple symmetrical set-up will help. A bar magnet is placed lengthwise on the axis of a circular wire loop, some way from the loop. We now move the loop steadily closer to the magnet at speed $v$.

The free electrons in the wire experience magnetic Lorentz forces, given by
$$\mathbf F=(-e)\mathbf v \times \mathbf B$$
It is these forces that drive the free electrons round the loop. The field lines from the magnet 'splay out' and if, in the vicinity of the loop, they make an angle $\theta$ with the loop axis, the magnitude of the tangential force on the electrons in the loop will be $evB\sin\theta$.
The emf is given by
$$|\mathscr E|=\frac {\text{work done on electron per circuit of the loop}}e=\frac{evB\sin\theta \times 2\pi r}e=2\pi rvB\sin\theta$$
**Notes**

(a) This is the *motional* emf that you asked about. The force giving rise to the emf is a magnetic force. If we'd kept the wire stationary and moved the magnet, the force  would be an electric one, due to a non-conservative electric field set up according to
$$\mathbf{\nabla}\times\mathbf E=-\frac{d\mathbf B}{dt}.$$ Re-assuringly, we get the same size of the emf when it is calculated in this way (that is in the frame of reference in which the wire is stationary), as the Principle of Relativity demands.

(b) $2\pi rv$ is the rate of sweeping out of area (a cylindrical band) by the loop. $B\sin\theta$ is the component of magnetic flux density normal to this area, so $2\pi rvB\sin\theta$ is the rate of cutting of flux by the loop, which is (using $\mathbf{\nabla}.\mathbf B =0$) the rate of change of flux through the loop. So we can cast our equation for $|\mathscr E|$ into the familiar Faraday form,
$$|\mathscr E|= \frac{d\Phi}{dt}.$$

(c) Note that, even if we move the loop towards the magnet at constant speed, $v$, the emf will not be constant. This is because $B\sin\theta$ increases as the loop approaches the magnet.

Comment: One of these days I'll read the date of the question before writing an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Because the current also flows *through* the battery. Actually in metallic conductors, it is the electrons which flows through the conductor. Read the mechanism of any simple cell, e.g. [Electrochemical cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochemical_cell). If the elctrons were not to flow through the battery then they would eventually diminish the charge at cathode and anode of the battery. Then the internal chemicals will agitate again to make cathode negative and anode positive untill the reaction is exothermic.

Comment: Perhaps I missed the word _motional_ before emf. Sorry my bad.

Comment: Motional emf is actually an induced electric field, which is a non conservative force. The $\vec E$ make loops. There are no cathode and anode.

Comment: I know that current is actually the flow of electrons but its direction is always shown as the flow of +ve charges and here also conventional current is considered (in my text book). It is written that once current begins to flow the amount of charges is reduced at the point which was initially at higher potential and when they reach the point which is at lower potential then they are carried back to the starting point by 'unbalanced magnetic force'I am not able to get this point.

Comment: @J.Doe What you need to understand is motional emf is an altogether different concept. Considering current as the flow of +ve charge is merely a convention. Usually higher potential is place with a lot of +ve charge and lower potential is plate with relatively lesser positive or completely negative charge. The electric field originates from higher potential place and ends at lower potential place. Any charge particle which comes in between _feels_ the electric field of that region. [cont].

Comment: In a usual battery there is an anode-- place with a lot of positive charge--high potential and a cathode -- place with a lot of negative charge. What happens is that Electric field lines originate from Anode and end at Cathode. The free electrons of the metal wire attached between these nodes feel that $\vec E$ and move from CAthode to Anode. [cont.]

Comment: The scanerio for motional emf is altogether different. There are no cathode and anode. When the magnetic flux through a closed loop of metal say a copper wire changes _Circular shaped loops of Electric field. This Electric field doesn't start from anode. Nor does it end at cathode.  IT is just a loop of Electric field lines. Any free electron that falls in those lines start moving opposite to $\vec E$. That causes a current.

Comment: Yes i do understand all of what you have written but the thing that i dont get is that how the applied magnetic field is 'unbalanced'?

Comment: There is nothing _balanced_ or _unbalanced_ about _applied magnetic field_. For motional emf to exist the strength of magnetic field at a particular point in space has to change with time.